# Need info on proto.properties file in java

Tags: java

I am completely new to java  . I would like to know what the proto.properties file is used for in programming. Any details on this is appreciated.

Regards
David

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/ Did you read this?

Answer (score 0):

Property files are files that store a property by using 2 parameters, one called the key, which is the variable name, and the other being the value which is what you assign to the key.

Remember that all values saved are Strings

Property files look something like this

```
# You are reading the ".properties" entry.
! The exclamation mark can also mark text as comments.
# The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with
# a preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded.
website = http\://en.wikipedia.org/
language = English
# The backslash below tells the application to continue reading
# the value onto the next line.
message = Welcome to \
          Wikipedia!
# Add spaces to the key
key\ with\ spaces = This is the value that could be looked up with the key "key with spaces"
# Unicode
tab : \u0009
```

Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Java properties file is used to store project configuration data or settings.

See the below example how to write to properties File in Java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("database", "AIXDB");
        prop.setProperty("dbuser", "mukesh");
        prop.setProperty("dbpassword", "password");

        // save properties to project root folder
        prop.store(output, null);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
  }
}



**Output**

config.properties

dbpassword=password
database=AIXDB
dbuser=mukesh
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Is the usage of this very common ? If I have a database wouldn't it be better to refer values from the database in my code rather than hardcoded values from the proto.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Properties are configuration values managed as key/value pairs. In each pair, the key and value are both String values. The key identifies, and is used to retrieve, the value, much as a variable name is used to retrieve the variable's value.

To manage properties, create instances of java.util.Properties. This class provides methods for the following:

- Loading key/value pairs into a Properties object from a stream
- Retrieving a value from its key
- Listing the keys and their values
- Saving the properties to a stream
- Properties extends java.util.Hashtable. Some of the methods inherited from Hashtable

For more details please follow Java doc link. [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)